# Move element to end of body and back to original place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below which is executed when a modal is opened on a webpage. It moves div id="header_cart" to the end of the body when the modal is opened.

```
      $(document).on('opening', '#modal', function (e) {
        $(document.body).append( $('#header_cart').detach() );
      });
```

But I also want div id="header_cart" to be returned to its original place when that modal is closing.

```
    $(document).on('closing', '#modal', function (e) {
        ........
    });
```

I am not a expert in javascript so I need help on what to add in place of the dots to make #header_cart return to its location after the modal box is close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need the ID of your `<div id="header_cart />` parent element.

Then (supposing the parent element has `header_cart_parent` as its ID), you just have to use :

```
$(document).on('closing', '#modal', function (e) {
    $('#header_cart_parent').append( $('#header_cart').detach() );
});
```

If you don't know the parent ID, you could always add an empty `div` where `<div id="header_cart />` was, on opening the modal, and then remove it on closing :

```
/** OPENING **/
$(document).on('opening', '#modal', function (e) {
    $('#header_cart').after('<div id="header_cart_after"></div>');
    $(document.body).append( $('#header_cart').detach() );
});

/** CLOSING **/
$(document).on('closing', '#modal', function (e) {
    $('#header_cart_after').before( $('#header_cart').detach() );
    $('#header_cart_after').detach();
});
```

Comment: This worked as explained. I could add a parent element so that option works for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Again add that element to its original place, like below code

```
<div id ="div1">Hello Div 1</div>
<div id ="div2">Hello Div 2</div>
<div id ="div3">Hello Div 3</div>
<button id ="div1button">Div1</button>
<button id ="div2button">Div2</button>
<button id ="div3button">Div3</button>

<script>
$("#div1button").click(function(){
    $("#div3").append( $('#div1').detach() );
})

$("#div3button").click(function(){
    $("#div2").prepend( $('#div1').detach() );
})
</script>
```

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what is wrong with this code. It will be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment. I downvoted your answer for two reasons : 1. Your code snippet has nothing in common with OP's question, you should really try to adapt it to the question. 2. `#div1` will never return to its original place in your example, it will be inside of `#div3` or inside of `#div2`, neither of which is its original position. You should consider using `before()` and `after()` instead of `prepend()` and `append()`

Comment: Thanks for your input.